# Very complex SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, complexity-theory

I've a complex query and I can't get the correct answer.
There are 3 tables:

*contact* (**pk** as INT, **name** as VARCHAR, ...)
*session* (**pk** as INT, **contact** as INT, ...)
*message* (**pk** as INT, **session** as INT, ...)

The `session.contact` points to `contact.pk`. And `message.session` to `session.pk`.
When `session.contact` is zero, then there is no contact for this row. `contact.pk` is never zero.

Now I want to get all names of the specific message. My try was this:

> SELECT message.pk, contact.name FROM message, session, contact WHERE message.session = session.pk AND session.contact = contact.pk

But I didn't get the correct number of rows returned. It should be 2459, there are 2075.

Comment: a) That's not very complex. b) How do you know what the correct answer is? Is it an exam question?

Comment: I think you need to outer join the table that sometimes has no entry (i.e. `session.contact=contact.pk` in your example is not going to find a match).

Comment: Are you trying to get records with no contact too? Your current query will not get those. That might be your shortage

Comment: Agree with Marc, I think you're looking for outer joins on tables where there may not be a matching row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, how do you know that is the correct number of rows?

Second, you should use proper `JOIN` syntax similar to below:

```
SELECT message.pk, contact.name
FROM message m
LEFT JOIN session s
    on m.session = s.pk
LEFT JOIN contact c
    on s.contact = c.pk
```

Comment: Too bad it wont change his results

Comment: @Shredder True, but it's a good idea to get them going down the right road for the future, no?

Comment: @Shredder: Think @bluefeet just edited the answer to include it, but `LEFT JOIN` will change his results.

Comment: @Shredder if they posted some sample data it would be very helpful in determining the proper syntax.